# What are the options for running GPU nodes in Paas on Azure?

Tags: gpu, azure, container

I want to spin up GPU nodes on demand to run a Python application on Azure.

It is a bit unclear as how I can accomplish this however. I got the impression that there were GPU nodes available in Azure Container Service, but now I am not so sure anymore.

So what options are there to do this?

Answer (score 0):

On Azure, [NC series and NV series VMs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-gpu) support GPU.

> The NC and NV sizes are also known as GPU-enabled instances. These are
>   specialized virtual machines that include NVIDIA's GPU cards,
>   optimized for different scenarios and use cases. The NV sizes are
>   optimized and designed for remote visualization, streaming, gaming,
>   encoding, and VDI scenarios utilizing frameworks such as OpenGL and
>   DirectX. The NC sizes are more optimized for compute-intensive and
>   network-intensive applications and algorithms, including CUDA- and
>   OpenCL-based applications and simulations.

But for now, Azure Container Service does not support select NC and NV VM as nodes. So, if possible, I suggest you could select VM(Iaas) to deploy your application on Azure.

Comment: More information about Azure VM size please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes).